# Classes of algebras where derived equivalence preserves the global dimension

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

> Question: Are there known classes $X$ of finite dimensional algebras in the literature that have the property that in case $A, B \in X$ are derived equivalent, they share the same global dimension?

Note that usually derived equivalences very rarely preserve the exact value of the global dimension, for example take a linear oriented hereditary algebra $kQ$ of Dynkin type $A_n$ which has global dimension one and is derived equivalent to its Koszul dual which has global dimension $n-1$.

A trivial class of examples is taking $X$ the class of semisimple algebras.
A non-trivial recent class is the class of algebras having a simple-preserving anti-duality, see theorem 5.10 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.03513.pdf (and this is the only non-trivial class I am aware of in the literature).